# To get same view which one is best: Linear or Relative Layout

Tags: xml, android-layout

In an interview I faced this question:

> There are two TextView horizontally. Below them there is an
>   ImageView. You can design the XML using LinearLayout or
>   RelativeLayout.
>
> Which one is efficient? and Why?

Please let me know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one you'll choose?

You should choose RelativeLayout.

> Why?

If you go for LinearLayout to implement this example then you have to use 2 Linear Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout vertical>

    <LinearLayout horizontal>
        <TextView/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView />
</LinearLayout>
```

But if you go for Relative Layout then you need only one Relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView/>
   <TextView/>
   <ImageView />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**This nested LinearLayout takes more time to render than single RelativeLayout according to this** [google developer link](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html)

Answer (score 1):

If I use LinearLayout then I have to at least 2 LinearLayout. 1 for the textview and another for the imageview (below textview). But if I use RelativeLayout then i can easily do it within 1 RelativeLayout using the below attribute (imageview below textview_id). As the code will contain less child it will be smoother than LinearLayout. So I will use the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

Relative Layout.
In Linear, 2 children view is needed but in Relative, only 1 child is neede. Which is more light weight and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Relative.. Weight style at case of Linear may achieve same result but will cost much memory..